# How to get certain JSON values from curl response

Tags: linux, shell, curl, command-line-interface

I'm trying to execute the below request payload (JSON) and getting the response back as below:

CURL command:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "hostname:kindle.qa.amazon.com" \
--request POST \
--data '{
"country":"BE",
"cardNumberPayment":"9423-8234-1882-3412",
"cardType" : "Visa",
"expirationMonth": "12",
"expirationYear": "2020"
}' \
  http://amazon.qa.payment.com/v1/Services/restservices/credit
```

**Response**:

```
{"cardType":"Visa","cardNumber":"9423823418823409","cvv":"***"}
{"cardType":"Visa","cardNumber":"9423823418823411","cvv":"***"}
{"cardType":"Visa","cardNumber":"9423823418823410","cvv":"***"}
```

I just want to get cardNumber for the curl command instead of printing the entire JSON (Except cardType, and cvv).

**Expected Output**:

```
9423823418823409
9423823418823411
9423823418823410
```

I just want to get the list of *card numbers* alone to print as output. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to use a JSON parser to extract the information. You can use jq to do that (jq is a lightweight and command-line JSON processor.)

This [article](https://medium.com/how-tos-for-coders/https-medium-com-how-tos-for-coders-parse-json-data-using-jq-and-curl-from-command-line-5aa8a05cd79b) describes more in detail how to achieve that. They also have a [tutorial here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/).

For instance

```
curl 'http://amazon.qa.payment.com/v1/Services/restservices/credit' | jq '.[0]'
```

would extract the first element of your array (assuming it's an array - your code makes it look like a series of objects).

Then to grab the card number do sthg along the lines of

```
jq '.[0] | .cardNumber'
```

There are several other examples in this [SO post too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools).